# TYPO3 extension migration

Tags: php, typo3

I'm trying to migrate an old extension from TYPO3 4.7 to 7.6. Problem is I do not get any error output, only having my backend refreshed which makes it difficult for the debugging. Maybe someone can see what's wrong in the code that's causing this. This extension has been developed on PHP 5.3, I'm using 5.6 on TYPO3 7.6.

```
$linksToApproveWithoutCategory = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->exec_SELECTgetRows( 'uid,label,pid,description,href', $theTable, $theField . '=' . $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->quoteStr( $theValue, $theTable ) . ' ' . $whereClause, $groupBy, $orderBy, $limit );



if(count($linksToApproveWithoutCategory) > 0) {
    // Links without category
    for($i = 0; $i < count($linksToApproveWithoutCategory); $i++) {
        $content .= '<form action="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '" method="POST">';

        // Alternating row colors
        $content .= $switch ? '<tr bgcolor="' . $doc['bgColor5'] . '">' : '<tr>' ;
        $switch = !$switch;

        // Starting content
        $content .= '<td style="vertical-align:top;"><input type="text" name="label" value="' . $linksToApproveWithoutCategory[$i]['label'] . '" size="30" /></td>';
        $content .= '<td><textarea name="description" rows="5">' . \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::formatForTextarea( $linksToApproveWithoutCategory[$i]['description'] ) . '</textarea></td>';
        $content .= '<td style="vertical-align:top;"><input type="text" name="href" value="' . $linksToApproveWithoutCategory[$i]['href'] . '" size="30" /></td>';

        $content .= '<td style="vertical-align:top;"><select name="categoryUID"><option value="0"></option>';

        foreach((array) $categories as $category) {
            $content .= '<option value="' . $category['uid'] . '">';

            if($category['parent_category'] > 0) {
                $content .= '-- ';
            }

            $content .= $category['label'] . '</option>';
        }
        $content .= '</select></td>';

        $content .= '<td style="vertical-align:top;"><input type="image" src="/fileadmin/user_upload/action_accept.gif" style="border:0px;" alt="' . $GLOBALS['LANG']->getLL( 'ViewLinksToApprove_accept' ) . '" title="' . $GLOBALS['LANG']->getLL( 'ViewLinksToApprove_accept' ) . '" /></td>';
        $content .= "<td style=\"vertical-align:top;\"><a href=\"?action=getViewDeleteLink&id=" . $this->id . "&uid=" . $linksToApproveWithoutCategory[$i]['uid'] . "\"><img src=/fileadmin/user_upload/action_delete.gif\" border=\"0\" alt=\"" . $GLOBALS['LANG']->getLL( 'ViewLinksToApprove_delete' ) . "\" title=\"" . $GLOBALS['LANG']->getLL( 'ViewLinksToApprove_delete' ) . "\"></a></td>";
        $content .= '</tr>';

        $content .= '<input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $this->id . '" /><input type="hidden" name="uid" value="' . $linksToApproveWithoutCategory[$i]['uid'] . '" /><input type="hidden" name="action" value="getViewAcceptLink" /></form>';
    }
}
```

I have changed some deprecated namespaces, but the refresh happens when pressing submit button.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the adaption for TYPO3 6.2

in 6.2 all the old classnames were still available. so your extension works and you can generate a deprecation log.

Maybe you can use the compatibility6 layer available in 7. otherwise you need to correct your old extension blindly: specify all classes with full namespaces, find replacements for deprecated functions and classes.

deprecation lists:
 - https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/7/html/deprecated.html
 - https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/62/html/deprecated.html
 - https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/61/html/deprecated.html
 - https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/60/html/deprecated.html
 - https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/47/html/deprecated.html
 - https://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/45/html/deprecated.html