# What is a good way to migrate old TYPO3 extensions

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions

I have to refactor a few very old TYPO3 extensions. they are compatible with ^4 but the company I'm working for now needs them for ^8 (the development for this extensions stopped for whatever reason).

I was wondering what is the best approach for me to get this task done -
are there some major resources I could use to get into that topic?
or a general changelog for TYPO3 extensions based on the version up from 4-9?

Any information is much appreciated.

Comment: why do people downvote this question? what is not ok with it?

Comment: I would say the best way to do it, it to completely rewrite the extensions. Since TYPO3 v4 a lot of have been changed and it has no meaning to just update them. Create a new extension which does the same thing with the old extension and that’s it. I upvoted the question. I don’t really get why someone would downvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying best to answer this, it's up to you how you maintain your site. Off course you need to check the complexity of the extension you build.

Check a few parameters below:

**1. Complexity of the extension**

Off course you have a big challenge to maintain code (Probably PI-Base extension). Your code should work with TYPO3 8.x as well as PHP 7.0.

**2. Code Scalability**

A simple thing, your code must be clean so understand better.

Now, you have two way to maintain your extension which is:

- Re-build
- Use existing extension (Migrate & make this compatible)

### **Re-build Extension**

If you don't have complex application in your web site, you can follow @Aristeidis Karavas and rebuild the completely new extension (Extbase approach off course).

I'll recommend, re-develop for better quality product and to get optimized speed! What do you say?

### **Migrate Extension**

For TER extension (which is available at [extensions.typo3.org](https://extensions.typo3.org/)) might provide migration extension, such as `EXT:tt_news` to `EXT:tx_news`. For the custom extension, you can write your own SQL script which migrates your extension data to the new extension.

**Compatibility Extension:**

You can use compatibility extension available at TER which provide some easy solution to map TYPO3 classes.

**Useful Links:**
Here is some useful link could bring you to the bright side and will make your stuff easier:

- [EXT:compatibility6](https://github.com/FriendsOfTYPO3/compatibility6/)
- [EXT:compatibility7](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/compatibility7/)
- [Blog: Upgrade Guide](https://www.nitsan.in/blog/post/the-ultimate-guide-on-typo3-upgrade/)
- [Bernd has given deprecation lists Links here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47903566/typo3-extension-migration?answertab=active#tab-top)

Hope this will help you!